# Peculiarities with Series and fractional exponents or bug?

Tags: series-expansion

The [documentation of the `Series[]` function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series.html) states that it can handle *"certain expansions involving negative powers, fractional powers, and logarithms."* What are the conditions that dictate whether a function falls into this class of "certain expansions?"

As impetus for this concern, I've shown a peculiarity found in using `Series` in conjunction with fractional powers below. Can this be explained in any way other than as a bug?

A contrived MWE where one finds the leading order expansion of $f(1+2\epsilon+5\epsilon^{3/2})$ about the point $\epsilon=0$:

```
In[1]:= Series[f[1 + 2 ϵ + 5 ϵ^(3/2)], {ϵ, 0, 0}]
Out[1]= SeriesData[ϵ, 0, {f[1]}, 0, 1, 2]
```

which works as it should. However, turning this into a multivariable function $f(1+2 \epsilon+5\epsilon^{3/2},x)$, `Series` can no longer returns the correct `SeriesData`.

```
In[2]:= Series[f[1 + 2 ϵ + 5 ϵ^(3/2), x], {ϵ, 0,0}]
Out[2]= f[1, x] + Derivative[1,0][f][1,x]
```

This sort of error does not occur when fractional exponents are absent in the argument of $f$. Why does this occur, and can it be prevented without completely avoiding expressions such as the one found above?

Answer (score 1):

This honestly seems like a bug to me, but I think it's not entirely due to fractional exponents. To see why, get rid of the fractional exponents by setting `ϵ=e^2` and finding `Series[f[1 + 2 ϵ + 5 ϵ^(3/2), x], {e, 0, 0}]` around `e=0` instead of `ϵ=0`. We see `Derivative[1,0][f][1,x]` disppears from the output, but the output still lacks the `SeriesData` head and thus the `O[e]`.

The following tests on arguments with only integer exponents suggest the `SeriesData` head gets lost when the smallest exponent greater than 0 is larger than 1, but smaller than the series order:

```
Series[f[e, x], {e, 0, 0}]
```

> SeriesData[e, 0, {f[0, x]}, 0, 1, 1]

```
Table[Series[f[e^2, x], {e, 0, n}], {n, 0, 3}]
```

> {f[0, x], f[0, x], SeriesData[e, 0, {f[0, x], 0, Derivative[1, 0][f][0, x]}, 0, 3, 1], SeriesData[e, 0, {f[0, x], 0, Derivative[1, 0][f][0, x]}, 0, 4, 1]}

```
Table[Series[f[e^3, x], {e, 0, n}], {n, 0, 3}]
```

> {f[0, x], f[0, x], f[0, x], SeriesData[e, 0, {f[0, x], 0, 0, Derivative[1, 0][f][0, x]}, 0, 4, 1]}

For `f[1 + 2 ϵ + 5 ϵ^(3/2), x]`, the smallest such exponent of `ϵ=e^2` is 2, so the `SeriesData` head is lost, when expanding to order 0 in `e`. As expected, the head is recovered when expanding to order 2 or more. Likewise, `Series[f[1 + 2 ϵ^(1/2) + 5 ϵ^(3/2), x], {e, 0, 0}]` is ok because the smallest exponent of e is 1.

Going back to arguments with fractional exponents, I had expected the same rule to apply to the argument obtained from a change of variables to eliminate fractional exponents. Alas, that is not exactly the case. `Clear[ϵ]` and `Series[f[1 + 2 ϵ + 5 ϵ^(3/2), x], {ϵ, 0, 1}]` is still wrong, even though this is equivalent to `Series[f[1 + 2 e^2 + 5 e^3, x], {e, 0, 2}]`. However, `Series[f[1 + 2 ϵ^(1/2) + 5 ϵ^(3/2), x], {ϵ, 0, 0}]` is fine, as when `ϵ` was set to `e^2`.

These observations have led me to the following fix - add a term to have exponent 1 under change of variables to an argument with only integer exponents, and set this term to 0 after the Series expansion. In this case:

```
Series[f[a ϵ^(1/2) + 1 + 2 ϵ + 5 ϵ^(3/2), x], {ϵ, 0, 0}] /. a->0
```

> SeriesData[[Epsilon], 0, {f[1, x]}, 0, 1, 2]

This solution requires knowing the appropriate change of variables - I'm not sure if this is always the one minimizing the resulting polynomial order. Therefore, the more robust solution is to delay using multivariate functions until after `Series` by e.g.

```
 Series[f[1 + 2 ϵ + 5 ϵ^(3/2)], {ϵ, 0, 0}] /. 
{f[y_] -> f[y, x], Derivative[i_][f][y_] -> Derivative[i, 0][f][y, x]}
```