# Successive Series Expansion Bug (?)

Tags: series-expansion

I've found what appears to be a bug in MMA related to taking successive series expansions.  I'm providing this minimal example and post as other posts didn't appear to address the issue I found.

In particular, MMA seems to get confused in keeping track of orders of parameters when future expansion parameters are in the powers of earlier expansion parameters, which seems to be due to a limitation of the [`SeriesData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesData.html) object that [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series.html) produces.

While it appears known that MMA may include extra powers, e.g. [Multivariable Taylor expansion does not work as expected](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15023/multivariable-taylor-expansion-does-not-work-as-expected), in my example MMA ***misses*** some critical terms.  For example

```
Series[x^z y^z (1 + x + y)/z, {x, 0, 0}, {y, 0, 0}, {z, 0, 1}] // Normal
```

yields the incorrect expression

$$
\frac{1}{z}+\log (x)+\log (y) + z \log (x) \log (y)
$$

whereas

```
Series[Series[Series[x^z y^z (1 + x + y)/z, {x, 0, 0}] //
  Normal, {y, 0, 0}] //Normal, {z, 0, 1}] // Normal
```

captures all the correct terms,

$$
\frac{1}{z}+\log (x)+\log (y) + \frac{1}{2} z \big( \log ^2(x)+2 \log (x) \log (y)+\log ^2(y) \big).
$$

It seems that the critical point is to ensure that one finds the correct answer, each `Series[]` result needs to be hit with a `Normal[]` first, before performing the next `Series[]`.

Interestingly, the first method does not miss any terms when I remove the $1/z$ from the expression to be expanded and ask for a series expansion up to $O(z^2)$, although the first method does then give some extra terms $O(z^3)$ and $O(z^4)$, too.

Possibly the bug (?) described above is related to [Peculiarities with Series and fractional exponents or bug?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91293/peculiarities-with-series-and-fractional-exponents-or-bug).

Comment: Please don't use the **BUGS** tag until the community find confirmation there is a bug.

Comment: Someone who has time might ponder `Series[x^z y^z (1 + x + y)/z, {z, 0, 1}] // FullForm` vs. `Series[x^z y^z (1 + x + y)/z, {y, 0, 0}, {x, 0, 0}] // FullForm`.

Comment: Hi Michael, according to the MMA documentation, Series evaluates its expansion from left to right; i.e. the two orderings given in my comment are the same.

Hi @rhermans, Michael has confirmed the discrepancy.  Getting two different results for what should be the same expression seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Per my response, this is not related to that "Pecularities with Series..." post. That one is for a univariate series whereas the difficulties here appear to be strictly a multivariate series phenomenon.

Comment: Hi Daniel, the similarity here and in "Peculiarities..." is that SeriesData[] is somewhat inflexible in the data it can contain (only rational powers of the small parameter).  Thus in the above example SeriesData[] cannot have powers of x^z inside, so it's pulled out front, as seen in FullForm.  Subsequent Series[] calls then do not correctly keep track of the expansion order and hence the incorrect result in the above example.

Comment: (1) This were fractional (as in rational) exponents, which are handled as Puiseux series. The issue there is that `Series` does not have a "natural" way to get fractional orders, since it wants an integer expansion.

Comment: (2) To repeat what i wrote elsewhere here, `Series` is behaving as expected for the example in this post. There is no "expansion order" for nonnumeric exponents. The input is outside the realm of what `Series` is documented to handle, so regard it as garbage in, garbage out if that helps.

Answer (score 9):

The order of evaluation business is confusing. It really does go from inside outward for `Series`. We can see this from the example under Generalizations and Extensions on the ref guide page.

Here is the example.

```
Series[Sin[x + y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}]
```

First we show the result of handling the variable `x`.

```
In[579]:= InputForm[Series[Sin[x + y], {x, 0, 3}]]
Out[579]//InputForm=
SeriesData[x, 0, {Sin[y], Cos[y], -Sin[y]/2, -Cos[y]/6}, 0, 4, 1]
```

The full result is basically the result of now going inside each series coefficient when handling the `y` terms.

```
In[576]:= InputForm[Series[Sin[x + y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}]]
Out[576]//InputForm=
SeriesData[x, 0, {SeriesData[y, 0, {1, 0, -1/6}, 1, 4, 1], 
  SeriesData[y, 0, {1, 0, -1/2}, 0, 4, 1], 
  SeriesData[y, 0, {-1/2, 0, 1/12}, 1, 4, 1], 
  SeriesData[y, 0, {-1/6, 0, 1/12}, 0, 4, 1]}, 0, 4, 1]
```

When we get to the example from this post, I'm not sure if what we see is a bug or a feature. The `InputForm` shows some levels of nesting of `z` that seem amiss. I'll take a closer look if I get a chance.

--- edit ---

It's a feature. Here is a simpler form of the input that elicits the same behavior. I'll show it in two separate steps.

```
In[1381]:= InputForm[s1 = Series[x^z (1 + x)/z, {x, 0, 0}]]
Out[1381]//InputForm=
x^z*SeriesData[x, 0, {z^(-1)}, 0, 1, 1]
```

Fine so far, all according to documented behavior. Now try to extract a series in `z`.

```
In[1382]:= InputForm[Series[s1, {z, 0, 1}]]
Out[1382]//InputForm=
SeriesData[z, 0, 
{SeriesData[x, 0, {SeriesData[z, 0, {1}, -1, 2, 1]}, 0, 1, 1],
SeriesData[x, 0,
 {SeriesData[z, 0, {Log[x]}, -1, 2, 1]}, 0, 1, 1]},  0, 2, 1]
```

We now have nested series in `z`. While not desirable, I don't see any clean way to circumvent this. The upshot is that, for a nested series, we can expect trouble when an outer series is presented something that has its variable both inside and outside of `SeriesData` objects.

As noted already in this thread, a viable way around this is to interpose `Normal` between nested series evaluations.

--- end edit ---

Comment: Hi Daniel, yes, I think you got to the heart of the matter, which is that SeriesData[] doesn't seem to be able to handle certain expressions (as was hinted at by @Michael-E2 and explored further by you).  Having multiple SeriesData[] expressions, possibly nested, _could_ be a feature, but it seems MMA _is not_ properly keeping track of orders of parameters, hence the bug that Series[x^z y^z (1 + x + y)/z, {x, 0, 0}, {y, 0, 0}, {z, 0, 1}] yields an incorrect result.  (I can't see how an expression yielding the wrong answer is a feature.)

Comment: It's a feature because it is being pushed outside its zone of operation. Per documentation: "Series can construct standard Taylor series, as well as certain expansions involving negative powers, fractional powers, and logarithms." The example in question has essential singularities at the origin in both `x` and `y`, as well as a "polynomial" factor. The request is for terms up to order zero, effectively removing an `x*y^z` and a `y*x^z` factor. When the process gets around to extracting the series in `z` we've thus lost what would become logs in `x` and `y`.